# Post Review on product through Amazon SP-API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nestjs, amazon-selling-partner-api

**Scenario**: I'm build a NodeJs (NestJs Framework) application, Where I can get feedback from my clients (Amazon Product Purchaser) and Post its review on my Amazon Product page. I have successfully validated Amazon Order ID using SP-API endpoint `sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com//orders/v0/orders/{orderId}`, but I can't find any SP-API endpoint through which I can post Product Review on my Amazon Product Page.

**Summary**: I am trying to find an API endpoint (Amazon SP-API) through which I can post ***buyer review collected on my own website***.

Answer (score 0):

This use-case is impossible through SP-API.
You can't post a review on behalf on an Amazon customer.
The only thing you can do is redirect the customer to the review page.
Eventually you can add a parameter to pre-fil the form with 5 stars.

Here is the URL pattern to do so:

```
/review/create-review?&asin={{ ASIN }}:5
```